# How can I find in which kernel function a particular syscall error originates from?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, trace

When a syscall fails, it returns an error code. Generally the man page is well written and careful reading already provide good hints to fix the error.

Sometimes however, the error is trickier and I want to find the line sending the error in the kernel, ideally, with the relevant stack trace.

When a program is stuck, I know I can get the kernel side stacktrace with:

```
cat /proc/[PID OR TID OF INTEREST]/stacktrace
```

However, when it is running and returning an error with no hangs, this is of little help.

Is there a way to get a stacktrace when an unknown function returns a specific error in a given syscall ?

Comment: There is a trick in case you know error code and source file responsible for issuing it. In that source file add after inclusion block the construction like *#undef EINVAL #define EINVAL \_\_LINE__* (two lines), where *EINVAL* is an error code you are interested in. Recompile and see the line number in the file that issued error.

Comment: Nice trick, this turns the error code into the line number. Might have some unexpected side-effects though ! In that case, I don't even know the source file, also I could do trial and error since there are not so many candidates.